# Python Self - TypeError: add_state() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to solve the stagecoach problem with agent based simulation.  I am trying to add the states to a Panda's dataframe.  However, when doing this, I am getting the error "TypeError: add_state() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)."  I have looked at other questions on Stackoverflow and tried the solutions, but there is something that I'm missing.

Can someone please give me some advice or hints as to why I keep getting this error?  Thank you for your time.

```
from __future__ import division
import random
import pandas as pd


class stagecoach():

    current_state = "A"
    home_state = "J"
    cost = 0

    index = range(1,20,1)
    columns = ["Current", "Choices", "Cost"]

    states = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=index)

    counter = 1

    def add_state(self, s_current, s_choices, s_cost):
        self.states.loc[self.counter] = [s_current, s_choices, s_cost]
        self.counter += 1

    add_state("A", "B", 2)
    add_state("A", "C", 4)
    add_state("A", "D", 3)
    add_state("B", "E", 7)
    add_state("B", "F", 4)
    add_state("B", "G", 6)
    add_state("C", "E", 3)
    add_state("C", "F", 2)
    add_state("C", "G", 4)
    add_state("D", "E", 4)
    add_state("D", "F", 1)
    add_state("D", "G", 5)
    add_state("E", "H", 1)
    add_state("E", "I", 4)
    add_state("F", "H", 6)
    add_state("F", "I", 3)
    add_state("G", "H", 3)
    add_state("G", "I", 3)
    add_state("H", "J", 3)
    add_state("I", "J", 4)



    def choose(self,state):
        states_to_choose = self.states[self.states.Current == state]
        random_path = random.randint(0,len(states_to_choose))
        current_state = states_to_choose[random_path]


    def run(self):
        while self.current_state != self.home_state:
            print(self.states)
            self.choose(self.current_state)
            print(self.current_state)
            self.cost += 1



game = stagecoach()
game.run()
```

Comment: The add_state method requires a self parameter. You can give it by calling self.add_state or by passing an instance of stagecoach. What you probably meant to do was put the add_state calls in the `__init__` method.

Comment: I think using a class this way is not right. It has so many side effects if you will create multple instances of it. Use new style classes and define the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing argument is the first, usually called `self`, which is passed automatically when you call the method on an instance of the class. But you are not calling `add_state()` on an instance: you are calling it as a plain function and must pass all four arguments. And you can't do that because you don't have any instances of the class, because you're still defining it.

You want to write an `__init__()` method that does the `add_state()` calls as well as all the other things that are currently in your class body. This way, there will be an instance on which to call `add.state()`!  Something like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.current_state = "A"
    self.home_state = "J"
    self.cost = 0

    self.index = range(1,20,1)
    self.columns = ["Current", "Choices", "Cost"]

    self.states = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=index)

    self.counter = 1

    self.add_state("A", "B", 2)
    self.add_state("A", "C", 4)
    self.add_state("A", "D", 3)
    # and so on
```